# How to generate multiple lists in a single pass array in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I need to generate 2 list from list of dicts like `{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', ...}`.
In functional style (but 2 pass):

```
list_key1 = map(itemgetter('key1'), any_list)
list_key2 = map(itemgetter('key2'), any_list)
```

In usual style (1 pass):

```
list_key1, list_key2 = [], []
for i in any_list:
    list_key1.append(i['key1'])
    list_key2.append(i['key2'])
```

Is there any way to do this in functinal style and 1 pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass multiple keys to `itemgetter`, `zip` the mapped output and then unpack it into two tuples:

```
list_key1, list_key2 = zip(*map(itemgetter('key1', 'key2'), any_list))
```

If you prefer the output to be two lists instead you can map them to the list constructor:

```
list_key1, list_key2 = map(list, zip(*map(itemgetter('key1', 'key2'), any_list)))
```